# Pointer value changing unexpectedly when passed to function

Tags: c, pointers

So I'm trying to implement an arrayList in C but I'm getting some errors. When i is 4 in the for loop in the main function, insertArrayList is called to insert the number 4. After inserting 4 into my contents array, the first 5 elements of my array are 0,1,2,3,4. But then after my call to PrintArray, the first element in my array changes 6422016. I can not figure out why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct ArrayList{
    int numItemsInserted;
    int size;
    int *contents;
};

void initializeArrayList(struct ArrayList *a, int size){
    (*a).numItemsInserted= floor(size / 2);
    (*a).size = size;
    (*a).contents = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
}

void PrintArray(struct ArrayList *a){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (*a).numItemsInserted; i++){
        printf("%i ", (*a).contents[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
struct ArrayList insertArrayList(struct ArrayList *a, int num){
    if((*a).numItemsInserted == (*a).size){
        int newContents[(*a).size * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < (*a).size; i++){
            newContents[i] = (*a).contents[i];
        }


        (*a).contents = newContents;
        (*a).size *= 2;

    }
    (*a).contents[(*a).numItemsInserted] = num;
    (*a).numItemsInserted += 1;
    PrintArray(a);
}


int main() {
    struct ArrayList a1;
    initializeArrayList(&a1, 1);
    for (int i =0; i < 10; i ++){
        if (i == 1){
            printf("a");

        }
        insertArrayList(&a1, i);
    }

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: FIrst, the prototype; `struct ArrayList insertArrayList(struct ArrayList *a, int num)` should probably be written to return a pointer to struct:  `struct ArrayList * insertArrayList(...`  Second, because it is not a `void` function, it needs a return statement at the bottom to return whatever type you finally decide to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*a).contents = newContents;` assigns the address of (the first element of) the local array `newContents` to `(*a).contents`. Once `ArrayList` returns, `newContents` ceases to exist in the C model of computing.

A proper way to grow an array is to use `realloc` to request a larger allocation. First, request more memory:

```
int *NewContents = realloc(a->contents, NumberOfElementsDesired * sizeof *NewContents);
```

Then, test whether the request succeeded or failed:

```
if (NewContents == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error, failed to allocate memory.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then, record the address of the new memory:

```
a->contents = NewContents;
```

After that, fill in the new items.

Comment: Shouldn't my way still work? I don't need newContents anymore. I just made it so that I could assign contents to it. I still don't understand how this relates to value of my pointer changing values.

Comment: @Jonathan: When `newContents` is defined inside a function with `int newContents[(*a).size * 2];`, a **temporary** array is created. It uses memory that is automatically allocated (usually on the hardware stack) during function execution and automatically deallocated when the function ends. After the function ends, that memory may be reused for other purposes. The statement `(*a).contents = newContents;` **permanently** records the address of `newContents` in `(*a).contents`. That means, when you later try to use `(*a).contents`, you are using memory that has been changed by something else.

Comment: @Jonathan: Also, your question does not say the pointer changed values. It says the first element of the array changed values. That is because `(*a).contents` is pointing to memory that is no longer reserved for use for the array `newContents`. Something in your program is using that memory for other purposes, and that changes the values there.

Comment: Okay, I think I might understand what you are trying to say. Let me try to restate. Since newContents array is temporary, the memory allocated for that array is now allowed to be manipulated by the program once the array is destroyed?

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes, the program may reuse the memory for other purposes.

Comment: Thanks, for the help! I understand now and got the program working.